# Cost of copying files between Amazon S3 buckets in different Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-transfer

I want to copy the S3 files in my account to a different AWS account.

How do I copy without a data transfer fee?

Example command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://sourceBucket/file s3://targetBucket/
```

Does it transfer files over the Internet or does AWS transfer over the internal network?

Data size: 71TB

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems like a question for AWS support rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TylerH, thank you for information but I want to know if there are any fees. Because I couldn't find the answer on the Google. I just want to share the experience of someone who has done this before.

Comment: The question of "are there any fees for doing X in product Y" is precisely the kind of question you should ask product Y's *official support team*. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming or about tools used primarily for programming. Whether some function of some service incurs a fee is off-topic here.

Comment: Okey I just got it. Thanks for information! I'm deleting the topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the source and destination buckets are in the **same Region**, then there is **no Data Transfer cost**.

A few **tips** when copying objects between buckets owned by different Accounts:

- You will need to use a set of credentials that has both `GetObject` permission on the source bucket and `PutObject` permission on the destination bucket
- If you are using credentials from the source account, then make sure you use `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` otherwise the destination account will not be able to access/read/delete the object. This is why it is often better to use credentials from the **destination** account to copy the object.

Comment: For reference, pricing explained at https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ says there's no charge for "Data transferred between S3 buckets in the same AWS Region."